# Putting arrows Properly in Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows

I have the following code

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows,shadows,calc,fit}
\usepackage{amsmath,bm,times}
\newcommand{\mx}[1]{\mathbf{\bm{#1}}} % Matrix command
\newcommand{\vc}[1]{\mathbf{\bm{#1}}} % Vector command

\begin{document}
% Define the layers to draw the diagram
\pgfdeclarelayer{background}
\pgfdeclarelayer{foreground}
\pgfsetlayers{background,main,foreground}

% Define block styles used later

\tikzstyle{sensor}=[draw, fill=blue!20, text width=5em, 
    text centered, minimum height=3em,drop shadow]
\tikzstyle{ann} = [above, text width=8em, text centered]
\tikzstyle{wa} = [sensor, text width=10em, fill=red!20, 
    minimum height=7em, rounded corners, drop shadow]
\tikzstyle{sc} = [sensor, text width=13em, fill=red!20, 
    minimum height=10em, rounded corners, drop shadow]

% Define distances for bordering
\def\blockdist{2.3}
\def\edgedist{2.5}
\def\nodedist{1em}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.8, transform shape]
\node (node1) [wa] {Block};
\path (node1.west)+(-3.2,-.28) node (text1) [ann] {Inputs};
\path [draw, ->] (text1.east) -- (node1.west);

\path (node1.south)+(0,-2) node (text2) [ann] {Output1};
\path [draw,->]   (node1.south)--(text2.north);

\path (node1.east)+(3.2,2.2) node (myNode1) [sensor] {Block1};
\path (myNode1.south)+(0,-1) node (myNode2) [sensor] {Block2};
\path (myNode2.south)+(0,-1) node (myNode3) [sensor] {Block3};
\path (myNode3.south)+(0,-1) node (myNode4) [sensor] {Block4};

\path [draw,->] (node1.east) -- (myNode1.west);
\path [draw,->] (node1.east) -- (myNode2.west);
\path [draw,->] (node1.east) -- (myNode3.west);
\path [draw,->] (node1.east) -- (myNode4.west);



\path (node1.east)+(8.5,0) node (text3) [ann] {Output2};

\path [draw,->] (myNode1.east) -- (text3.west);
\path [draw,->] (myNode2.east) -- (text3.west);
\path [draw,->] (myNode3.east) -- (text3.west);
\path [draw,->] (myNode4.east) -- (text3.west);



\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

The above code give me the following figure

[image]

As you can see the arrows are not looking good (it should be thicker to be clearly visible). Also I am not able to draw all the arrows properly at the right most point where all arrows are pointing to a single point. What will be the issue?

Comment: Not looking good is only relative. It will be easy for us to know how you want them to be like.

Comment: @HarishKumar: Thanks for your comment. I have updated the question.

Comment: How about a helper coordinate west of `Output 2` for joining all the lines and drawing one arrow from it to `Output 2`. If you want thicker arrows you could try `>=triangle 45` in your path command.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Will you be happy with this?

```
\documentclass[border=4]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows,shadows,calc,fit,positioning}
\usepackage{amsmath,bm,times}
\newcommand{\mx}[1]{\mathbf{\bm{#1}}} % Matrix command
\newcommand{\vc}[1]{\mathbf{\bm{#1}}} % Vector command

\begin{document}
% Define the layers to draw the diagram
\pgfdeclarelayer{background}
\pgfdeclarelayer{foreground}
\pgfsetlayers{background,main,foreground}

% Define block styles used later

\tikzset{sensor/.style={draw, fill=blue!20, text width=5em,
                          text centered, minimum height=3em,drop shadow},
         ann/.style = {align=center},
         wa/.style = {sensor, text width=10em, fill=red!20,
                          minimum height=7em, rounded corners, drop shadow},
         sc/.style = {sensor, text width=13em, fill=red!20,
                         minimum height=10em, rounded corners, drop shadow}
    }

% Define distances for bordering
\def\blockdist{2.3}
\def\edgedist{2.5}
\def\nodedist{1em}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.8,>=latex]
\node[wa] (node1)  {Block};
\node[left= 1.25cm of node1,ann] (text1)  {Inputs};
\draw [thick,->] (text1.east) -- (node1.west);

\node[below= 1.25cm of node1,ann] (text2) {Output1};
\draw [thick,->]   (node1.south)--(text2.north);

\node[above right= 0.6cm and 1.5cm of node1,sensor] (myNode1) {Block1};
\node[above right= -1cm and 1.5cm of node1,sensor] (myNode2) {Block2};
\node[below right= -1cm and 1.5cm of node1,sensor] (myNode3) {Block3};
\node[below right= 0.6cm and 1.5cm of node1,sensor] (myNode4){Block4};

\draw[thick,->] (node1.east) to[in=180,out=20] (myNode1.west);
\draw[thick,->] (node1.east) to[in=180,out=5] (myNode2.west);
\draw[thick,->] (node1.east) to[in=180,out=-5] (myNode3.west);
\draw[thick,->] (node1.east) to[in=180,out=-20] (myNode4.west);



\node[ann] (text3) at ([xshift=4.2cm]$(myNode2)!0.5!(myNode3)$) {Output2};

\draw[thick,->] (myNode1.east) to[in=180,out=0] (text3);
\draw[thick,->] (myNode2.east) to[in=180,out=0] (text3);
\draw[thick,->] (myNode3.east) to[in=180,out=0] (text3);
\draw[thick,->] (myNode4.east) to[in=180,out=0] (text3);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Is this any better? I have used stealth arrows and put the arrow heads out of the blocks 80% along the line rather than at the very end.

[image]

It's just a minor hack of your code:

```
\documentclass[border=5mm,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows,shadows,calc,fit,arrows,decorations.markings}
\tikzset{%
  ->-/.style={decoration={markings, mark=at position 0.8 with {\arrow{stealth}}},
              postaction={decorate}}
}
\usepackage{amsmath,bm,times}
\newcommand{\mx}[1]{\mathbf{\bm{#1}}} % Matrix command
\newcommand{\vc}[1]{\mathbf{\bm{#1}}} % Vector command


\begin{document}
% Define the layers to draw the diagram
\pgfdeclarelayer{background}
\pgfdeclarelayer{foreground}
\pgfsetlayers{background,main,foreground}

% Define block styles used later

\tikzstyle{sensor}=[draw, fill=blue!20, text width=5em,
    text centered, minimum height=3em,drop shadow]
\tikzstyle{ann} = [above, text width=8em, text centered]
\tikzstyle{wa} = [sensor, text width=10em, fill=red!20,
    minimum height=7em, rounded corners, drop shadow]
\tikzstyle{sc} = [sensor, text width=13em, fill=red!20,
    minimum height=10em, rounded corners, drop shadow]

% Define distances for bordering
\def\blockdist{2.3}
\def\edgedist{2.5}
\def\nodedist{1em}

\begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth,scale=.8, transform shape]
\node (node1) [wa] {Block};
\path (node1.west)+(-3.2,-.28) node (text1) [ann] {Inputs};
\path [draw, ->] (text1.east) -- (node1.west);

\path (node1.south)+(0,-2) node (text2) [ann] {Output1};
\path [draw,->]   (node1.south)--(text2.north);

\path (node1.east)+(3.2,2.2) node (myNode1) [sensor] {Block1};
\path (myNode1.south)+(0,-1) node (myNode2) [sensor] {Block2};
\path (myNode2.south)+(0,-1) node (myNode3) [sensor] {Block3};
\path (myNode3.south)+(0,-1) node (myNode4) [sensor] {Block4};

\path [draw,->-] (node1.east) -- (myNode1.west);
\path [draw,->-] (node1.east) -- (myNode2.west);
\path [draw,->-] (node1.east) -- (myNode3.west);
\path [draw,->-] (node1.east) -- (myNode4.west);



\path (node1.east)+(8.5,0) node (text3) [ann] {Output2};

\path [draw,->-] (myNode1.east) -- (text3.west);
\path [draw,->-] (myNode2.east) -- (text3.west);
\path [draw,->-] (myNode3.east) -- (text3.west);
\path [draw,->-] (myNode4.east) -- (text3.west);

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I found the answer given by Harish Kumar more appealing.

Comment: @Sooraj I agree. Harish's answer is much better!